# How to create array for datalayers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, google-tag-manager

I need to create a datalayer for carousel slideshow, this get data dynamically and I need inject an array.  I have de next code:

HTML

```
<div class="flex-slider" id="myCarousel">
    <ul class="" id="flex-list">
        <li class="views_slideshow" id="sliderWeb-1">
            <h1>My Title slider 1</h1>
            <h3>This cretive name 1</h3>
        </li>
        <li class="views_slideshow" id="sliderWeb-2">
            <h1>My Title slider 2</h1>
            <h3>This cretive name 2</h3>
        </li>
        <li class="views_slideshow" id="sliderWeb-3">
            <h1>My Title slider 3</h1>
            <h3>This cretive name 3</h3>
        </li>
        <li class="views_slideshow" id="sliderWeb-4">
            <h1>My Title slider 4</h1>
            <h3>This cretive name 4</h3>
        </li>
        <li class="views_slideshow" id="sliderWeb-5">
            <h1>My Title slider 5</h1>
            <h3>This cretive name 5</h3>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I´ve tested this script function with alert in the browser and this work fine:

```
var listSlider=$('#myCarousel li.views_slideshow');
listSlider.each(function () {
    var myID= this.id;
    var myName = $(this).find( "h1" ).text();
    var creative = $(this).find( "h3" ).text();
    var position=myID.split("-")[1];
});
```

Now.. my question is: with this data, how to create the next datalayer for tag manager?
I need pass data from function to next array

```
dataLayer.push({
    'ecommerce' : {
        'promoView' : {
            'promotions' : [ 
            {
                'id' : 'sliderWeb-1' ,
                'name' : 'My Title slider 1' ,
                'creative' : 'This cretive name 1' ,
                'position' : '1'
            },
            {
                'id' : 'sliderWeb-2' ,
                'name' : 'My Title slider 2' ,
                'creative' : 'This cretive name 2' ,
                'position' : '2'
            },
            {
                'id' : 'sliderWeb-3' ,
                'name' : 'My Title slider 3' ,
                'creative' : 'This cretive name 3' ,
                'position' : '3'
            },
            {
                'id' : 'sliderWeb-4' ,
                'name' : 'My Title slider 4' ,
                'creative' : 'This cretive name 4' ,
                'position' : '4'
            },
            {
                'id' : 'sliderWeb-5' ,
                'name' : 'My Title slider 5' ,
                'creative' : 'This cretive name 5' ,
                'position' : '5'
            }
            ]
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: `var myID= $(this).id;` Is invalid.  jQuery does not expose dom properties on itself, which is why the `prop()` method exists.  Either change that to `var myID= $(this).prop('id');` or just make it simply `var myID= this.id;`

Comment: Hi Taplar! thank you for the comment..